# Change message using javascript for specific time zone

Tags: javascript, timezone

I have some code which adds specific text depending on the time of day and day of the week. I want this to work for Central Standard Time, as our office is located in Texas. I am not a javascript guy so any advice would be welcome. I don't want a user in NY to see the message based on their time zone.

```
var day = new Date();
var hr = day.getHours();
    
    
 if ((day.getDay() == 0 || day.getDay() == 6)) {
      greeting = "phone number one";  }    
 
else if ((hr >= 8) && (hr <= 17))  {
    greeting = "phone number one";
}
      

else if ((hr <= 8) && (hr >= 17))  {
    greeting = "phone number two";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript is executed on client side.
For me in Germany, `new Date().getHours();` returns `22`.

For you, that will be 15 right now.

Therefore, there is no need for anything special, it just works as expected.